# compute the adjoint operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Suppose there is a bounded linear operator $T:L^2[-1,1]\to L^2[-1,1]$ given by $Tf(t)=\int_{-1}^0f(s)ds+(\int_{-1}^1f(s)ds)t^2$. We need to compute the adjoint of the operator $T$.
When I calculate the integral, I computed as this. \begin{aligned}\langle Tf(t)g(t)\rangle&=\int_{-1}^1[\int_{-1}^0f(s)ds+(\int_{-1}^1f(s)ds)t^2]g(t)dt\\&=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^0f(s)dsg(t)dt+\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1f(s)dst^2g(t)dt\\&=\int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^1f(s)g(t)dtds+\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1f(s)t^2g(t)dtds.\end{aligned}
I don't know whether my calculation is correct and I don't know how to compute the next step.

Comment: What you have done is correct. Can you write this as $\int_{-1}^1 f(s) Ag(s) \, ds$? In this  case $A$ will be the adjoint of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it helps to combine the terms differently

\begin{align*}
Tf(t)
&=
(1+t^2)\int_{-1}^0
f(s)
ds
+
t^2\int_{0}^1
f(s)
ds
\\
\end{align*}

We then have

\begin{align*}
<Tf,g>
&=
\int_{-1}^1
\left(
(1+t^2)\int_{-1}^0
f(s)
ds
+
t^2\int_{0}^1
f(s)
ds
\right)
g(t)
dt
\\
&=
\int_{-1}^0
f(s)
\int_{-1}^1
(1+t^2)g(t)
dtds
+
\int_{0}^1
f(s)
\int_{-1}^1
t^2g(t)
dtds
\end{align*}

and we can define

\begin{equation*}
h(s)
=
\begin{cases}
\int_{-1}^1
(1+t^2)g(t)
dt,& s<0\\
\int_{-1}^1
t^2g(t)
dt,
& 
s\geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

**Adding Clarification**

To finish, we see that

\begin{align*}
<Tf,g> 
&=
\int_{-1}^0
f(s)
h(s)
ds
+
\int_{0}^1
f(s)
h(s)
ds \\
&= 
\int_{-1}^{1}f(s)h(s)ds
\end{align*}

so

\begin{equation*}
T^*g(s)
=
\begin{cases}
\int_{-1}^1
(1+t^2)g(t)
dt,& s<0\\
\int_{-1}^1
t^2g(t)
dt,
& 
s\geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know how to find $T^*$ after you define $h(s)$. I don't know how to translate $\int_{-1}^0f(s)\int_{-1}^1(1+t^2)g(t)dtds$ to $\int_{-1}^1f(s)T^*g(s)ds$.

Comment: I added some explanation